JsonbTypeDeserializer on enum not invoked
I have this simple enumeration which is generated by OpenAPI code generation using enumOuterClass.mustache.
@JsonbTypeSerializer(Address.Serializer.class)
@JsonbTypeDeserializer(Address.Deserializer.class)
public enum Address {
  MAIN_ADDRESS("Main_Address"),
  DELIVERY_ADDRESS("Delivery_Address");

  private String value;

  Address(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String value() {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return value;
  }

  public static final class AddressDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<Address> {
    @Override
    public Address deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx, Type rtType) {
      String value;
      try {
        value = parser.getString();
      } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ise) {
        return null;
      }
      for (Address b : Address.values()) {
        if (b.value().equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + parser.getString() + "'");
    }
  }

  public static final class AddressSerializer implements JsonbSerializer<Address> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Address obj, JsonGenerator generator, SerializationContext ctx) {
      generator.write(obj.value);
    }
  }

}

Now I have written a simple test for serialization and deserialization of the enum values:
  @Test
  void addressEnumTest() throws Exception {
    try (Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create()) {
      for (Address a : Address.values()) {
        String json = jsonb.toJson(a);
        assertEquals("\"" + a.value() + "\"", json);

        Address result = jsonb.fromJson(json, Address.class);
        assertEquals(a, result);
      }
    }
  }

The serialization works perfectly while debugging and the breakpoints set are hit.
The deserialization is never called and my breakpoints there are not hit.
While continue the test I receive the following error:
jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: No enum constant Address.Main_Address.
If the value in JSON is written uppercase it works, but then my own deserializer is also never called.
How can I implement that my own deserializer is called?
I searched a lot on google but found only old stuff from 2020.
Some interesting links where

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/221
JSON Binding @JsonbTypeDeserializer annotation ignored on enums?


In class AddressDeserializer inside the loop, instead of equals() try using equalsIgnoreCase() this change will make sure that the deserialization works regardless of whether the JSON string is in uppercase or lowercase. which I think is the issue here

Hey @Hagelslag,
Thank you for the reply. I already tried it, but the real problem is that this deserializer is never used when deserializing the shown enum.

Have you check the configuration of your Jsonb if your enum handler has been correctly registered?

Hello sigur,
Thanks for the question. I think this should not be necessary. In the docs I have found that you can use a JsonbConfig and call the method withDeserializers OR you can use the annotation JsonbTypeDeserializer.
